# Use appsettings.json to configure DbContext mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using .netCore and Entity Framework to get some data from an SQL Database.
I have setup a `DbContext`

```
public partial class DashboardContext : DbContext
{
    public NotfallDashboardContext(DbContextOptions<NotfallDashboardContext> options) : base(options) {}

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<DashboardData>(entity =>
        {
            ...
        }
    }

    public virtual DbSet<DashboardData> DashboardData { get; set; }
}
```

and inject it into my controller with the following setup

```
services.AddDbContext<DashboardContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DashboardDatabase")));
```

Now the `DashboardData` class uses the `Table` Attirbute to connect to the correct table and schema.

```
[Table("TableName", Schema = "dbo")]
public partial class DashboardData
{
    ...
}
```

---

> What i would like to do, is to extract these two strings "TableName" and "dbo" into my appsettings.json configuration. I already added the configuration to appsettings, made a TableConfiguration class and setup dependency injection:

TableConfiguration.cs

```
public class TableConfiguration
{
    public string DatabaseView { get; set; }
    public string DatabaseSchema { get; set; }
}
```

appsettings.json

```
"TableConfiguration": {
    "DatabaseTable": "TableName",
    "DatabaseSchema": "dbo"
}
```

startup.cs

```
services.Configure<TableConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("TableConfiguration"));
```

> Is it possible to inject or otherwise use the configuration in the DasboardData Attribute?

Comment: What version of EntityFramework?

Comment: I'm using EF Core 1.0.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically changing schema in Entity Framework Core](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39499470/dynamically-changing-schema-in-entity-framework-core)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `Startup.cs`:

```
services.Configure<TableConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("TableConfiguration"));
```

Then, inject `IOptions<TableConfiguration> tableConf` into your context and store it for later usage by your `OnModelCreating()`:

```
public class DashboardContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly TableConfiguration tableConf;

    public DashboardContext(DbContextOptions<DashboardContext> options, IOptions<TableConfiguration> tableConf) : base(options)
    {
        this.tableConf = tableConf.Value;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<DashboardData>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable(this.tableConf.DatabaseTable, this.tableConf.DatabaseSchema);
        });
    }

    public virtual DbSet<DashboardData> DashboardData { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for! Thank you