# How do I enforce an either-or relationship between model properties, using EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I'm using EF Core.

My `Customer` entity has properties `Address1`, `Address2`, and `AddressFull`.

Depending on which system sends me the data, I may receive `Address1` and `Address2`, or I may receive `AddressFull`.

So I need:

- EITHER `Address1` and `Address2` required, and `AddressFull` not-required
- OR `Address1` and `Address2` not-required, and `AddressFull` required

So I have:

```
  entityTypeBuilder.Property(p => p.Address1).IsRequired(false);
  entityTypeBuilder.Property(p => p.Address2).IsRequired(false);
  entityTypeBuilder.Property(p => p.AddressFull).IsRequired(false);
```

But this config does not properly map to my domain, and I want to enforce the logic. Is that possible in EF Core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, there are two ways to implement this type of complex domain logic. You can do it in the database using `CHECK` constraints or triggers, or you can do it in your domain objects and check them during `SaveChanges`. Here is an example of the latter.

```
class MyEntity : IValidatableObject
{
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Address1)
            && string.IsNullOrEmpty(Address2)
            && string.IsNullOrEmpty(AddressFull))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("An address is required.");
        }
    }
}

class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var entities = from e in ChangeTracker.Entries()
                       where e.State == EntityState.Added
                           || e.State == EntityState.Modified
                       select e.Entity;
        foreach (var entity in entities)
        {
            var validationContext = new ValidationContext(entity);
            Validator.ValidateObject(
                entity,
                validationContext,
                validateAllProperties: true);
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this validates all entities instead of only those with complex validation, e.g. `MyEntity`? So should we add `where e is IValidatableObject` to filter for those ones?

Comment: Correct. It mimics some of the behavior of EF6 where where any `ValidationAttribute`s (e.g. `[Required]` and `[StringLength]`) will also get validated before sending the changes to the database which may save you some network traffic.

Comment: Sorry now I'm more confused. What I mean is the above code will try validate all entities, even if they don't implement `IValidatableObject`. What I was trying to ask is whether that's a good idea? Surely it will throw? That's why I though to filter `entities` using the `where e is IValidatableObject` line... In other words, isn't your code missing that line?

Comment: `Validator` is a general-purpose validation mechanism. If a class doesn't implement `IValidatableObject` or have any `ValidationAttribute`s on it or its members, it will consider the object valid and do nothing.

Comment: See [my blog post](http://www.bricelam.net/2016/12/13/validation-in-efcore.html) for a bit more context.

Comment: Ok makes sense now! It wasn't clear because the docs don't mention that it's a no-op in that case... Thanks.

Comment: PS for others stumbling onto this, keep in mind that if validation fails, it throws a `ValidationException`.

Comment: I wonder [if it's possible to get the original values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41771376/how-do-i-get-a-propertys-original-value-while-validating-in-ef-core) using your method?

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow for your DbContext different mapping according to your scenario, you can check this answer to enable in your DbContext change the mapping:

[Dynamically changing schema in Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39499470/dynamically-changing-schema-in-entity-framework-core/39631404#39631404)