# How do I get a property's original value while validating, in EF Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

In EF Core, there is a neat way to [perform entity validation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41106801/7059613) using `IValidatableObject`.

During validation I have the current value, but I also need access to the original value.

This is the validation method:

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext) { }
```

Is there some way to get access to the object's original values as well? I think the key is in `ValidationContext` but I'm not sure how.

Comment: You can gain access to the context if you want: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31527559/861716

Comment: @Gert Thanks, I suppose that is one way. However It's probably not the "cleanest" way to do this - the entity shouldn't have access to all that power. I hope it's possible to find the original values some other way. The `ValidationContext` has some kind of service object overload, but I'm not yet sure how to use it.