# Dynamic data seeding migration-generation in EF Core 2.1 depending on DbContext bool-flag with usage in OnModelCreating()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

## Current situation

Hello, I have a dotnet standard library in which I use **EF Core 2.1.1** (code first approach) to access the persistence layer. To create migrations I use a separate dotnet core console application (in the same solution) that contains an `IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<T>` implementation.
It is necessary to seed some data and I want to realize it in a comfortable way because in future the data to seed will be extended or rather modified. Therefore in implemented `IEntityTypeConfiguration` I use the extension method `.HasData()` which gets an array of objects to seed. The array will be provided from a separate class (`TemplateReader`), which loads the objects from a JSON file (in which extending and modifying work will be done). Hence it is possible to modify the JSON file's content and add a new migration that will contain generated code to Insert (`modelBuilder.InsertData()`), Update (`modelBuilder.UpdateData()`) or Delete (`modelBuilder.DeleteData()`) statements.
Because I will not ship the JSON file and I want to avoid loading the serialized data for seeding and the execution of `.HasData()`, I want to use a `bool` value that will be given into `DbContext` by the constructor.
To avoid bool value usage if it is not necessary to call the seeding for migration (and `.HasData()`) I have an overloaded constructor implemented with default value false.
Furthermore, I will not use `OnConfiguring` because I want to be flexible to set up `DbContextOptions<T>` object in my IoC container or separately for tests.

---

### Code

*The following code contains renamed variables to be more anonym about project's content, but represents current implemented logic.*

**MyDesignTimeDbContextFactory**:

```
public class MyDesignTimeDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<MyDbContext>
{
    public MyDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SqlServer"].ConnectionString;

        var contextOptionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyDbContext>()
            .UseSqlServer(connectionString);

        return new MyDbContext(contextOptionsBuilder.Options, true);
    }
}
```

**MyDbContext**:

```
public sealed class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly bool _shouldSeedData;


    public DbSet<Content> Contents { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Template> Templates { get; set; }


    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options, bool shouldSeedData = false) :
        base(options)
    {
        ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;

        _shouldSeedData = shouldSeedData;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("mySchema");

        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new TemplateTypeConfiguration(_shouldSeedData));

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

**TemplateTypeConfiguration**:

```
public class TemplateTypeConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Template>
{
    private readonly bool _shouldSeedData;


    public TemplateTypeConfiguration(bool shouldSeedData)
    {
        _shouldSeedData = shouldSeedData;
    }


    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Template> builder)
    {
        builder.Property(p => p.ModuleKey)
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(p => p.Html)
            .IsRequired();


        if (_shouldSeedData)
        {
            // reads all templates from configuration file for seeding
            var templateReader = new TemplateReader(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());

            var templates = templateReader.GetTemplates().ToArray();

            builder.HasData(templates);
        }
    }
}
```

**Template** (*entity*):

```
public class Template
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ModuleKey { get; set; }

    public string Html { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Content> Contents { get; set; }
}
```

---

## Problem

As far as I know and I already tested the `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder)` will be called before constructor's bool value will be set in the constructor (`_shouldSeedData = shouldSeedData;`). That's because the *base constructor* will be called immediately, followed by mine. Hence `_shouldSeedData`'s value is `false` when it will be given into `TemplateTypeConfiguration`.
Because of that, an `Add-Migration` results in an "empty" migration without any logic, if I have any modified the above-mentioned JSON file.

---

## Already tested approaches

I already tried to use `IModelCacheKeyFactory` with an own `ModelCacheKey` object without any success. As the template, I used this [SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979215/how-to-implement-imodelcachekeyfactory-in-ef-core).

Another approach I tested was to set up `_shouldSeedData` as `public static` variable and setting it from `MyDesignTimeDbContextFactory` to `true`, but in my opinion, it's a very dirty solution that I want to avoid to implement in production code.

It should be also possible to use `DbContextOptionsBuilder<T>`'s `UseModel(IModel)` extension method to avoid the usage of `OnModelCreating` and initializing `TemplateTypeConfiguration` with needed `shouldSeedData = false`. A disadvantage of this approach is to have duplicated code that will differ in `TemplateTypeConfiguration`'s constructor value. In my opinion as nasty as the public static approach.

---

## Question

Is there a clean solution to achieve to set `_shouldSeedData` by the constructor that `OnModelCreating` could use it with correct value (`true`) on design time?
In production it should be `false` and mentioned `TemplateReader` in `TemplateTypeConfiguration` should not be called because of if-condition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`OnModelCreating` is **not** triggered by the base `DbContext` constructor call, so there is absolutely no problem of saving the passed arguments to class members.

In your concrete scenario, the `OnModelCreating` is triggered by the accessing the `ChangeTracker` property before storing the passed argument:

```
public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options, bool shouldSeedData = false) :
    base(options)
{
    ChangeTracker.LazyLoadingEnabled = false; // <--

    _shouldSeedData = shouldSeedData;
}
```

Simply exchange the lines and the problem will be solved. And in general, always initialize your class members before accessing any context property.

Comment: Well, you're right! I had no idea that calling the `ChangeTracker` will result in calling `OnModelCreating`.
Do you have an article, book or something else with detailed information about such internal matter?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nope. Almost everything in EF Core is lazy initialized on first access, so it's virtually impossible to document every place which can trigger the model creation. That's why for safety reasons I would assume not calling / accessing any property / method before storing your own stuff.