# .Net Core 3.1 Entity Framework - copy existing tables structure to another schema

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a SAAS application which handle a multi tenant functionality.

I am planning to use different schema for each client.

My tables are created in .NET Core 3.1 using Entity Framework Core with a code-first approach and default schema `dbo`.

Now, whenever a client is created through the application, I want to create a same copy of `dbo` schema tables structure to another schema

For example: consider I have a table called `dbo.Product`, when Client A is registered, I need to create a table with `ClientA.Product`

How can I handle dynamic creation of tables in .NET Core 3.1 / Entity Framework Core?

Comment: That approach will create many problems and solve few.  It's generally a better practice, and easier, to have a separate database per tenant.

Comment: You can consider to add a field for each table where store the customerId (like dynamics ax), and split SQL table to different files.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft ,I have a micro service  based architecture , we are planning to host in some cloud platform , If I use separate database for each tenant , It will end up with huge number of database

Comment: @Max Since It's a cloud based SAAS application, It's very difficult to manage data backups and data a analysis for each client if store tenantid in all my tables

Comment: On a cloud platform having a "huge number of databases" is typically much more flexible and useful, and even cheaper than what you're proposing.   A SQL Server database is a unit of backup, HA, scale, security, versioning, deployment etc.  And is a natural fit for separating tenants data.  See eg: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-pool-overview

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I agree with you, but do we have any way to copy table structure from one schema to another schema ?

Comment: Start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41979215/how-to-implement-imodelcachekeyfactory-in-ef-core and here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/history-table