# Change EF Core context's connection string at runtime

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

It used to be possible to change a context's connection string, *after it was created.*

I can't figure out how to do that with EF Core (and SQLite). I'm registering the context in the usual way, using the ASP.NET Core builtin IoC container.

```
services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
  options.UseSqlite(cfg.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

I can't change the `MyContext` class, as it's in a separate assembly which is the responsibility of someone else. So I can't change the constructor, `OnConfiguring()`, etc.

So I need to re-create/init the container's current instance, using a new connection string.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: pleas share your startup.cs

Answer (score -2):

Sure, yo can do it by `ConfigurationBuilder` in `Startup`

```
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
    Configuration = builder.Build();
```

And then use it in your context. If `ConfigurationBuilder` have `reloadOnChange: true` will be reloaded on change

Comment: I assume the OP means they want to pass a different connection string at runtime, not by modifying the configuration.

Comment: Does container read the config every time it creates a new context instance? Doesn't look like it as it doesn't take a lambda, only a string `options.UseSqlite(connectionString)`. Even if so, I need to change the connection string *programmatically*, so I can't edit the file every time. Is there a way to do that in code?

Comment: You can create a function what will change `appsettings.json`

Comment: ... which will then affect already instantiated contexts. Again, unclear whether the OP wants that.

Comment: @CodeCaster I want to be able to change the connection string for new context instances. But changing the config file won't do that, I don't think so anyway. As I wrote above, the DbContext configuration doesn't take a delegate, only a string. So once it's set, it's set and cannot be changed.

Comment: Maybe this is useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39499470/dynamically-changing-schema-in-entity-framework-core/39631404?noredirect=1#comment66569390_39631404