# How to define schema table level

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1, ef-core-2.1

I am using EF Core 2.1 with C# for my application.

For some reason, there are a few tables for which I want the schema to be `dbo` while for others `app`

```
public class MyAppContext : DbContext
{
    private const string _dbSchema = "app";

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema(_dbSchema);
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new RegionConfiguration());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

While for some entities, I want to override the default schema & set it.

```
public class RegionConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Region>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Region> builder)
    {
        // Didn't find any such method -> builder.HasSchema("dbo"); 
        builder.HasKey(x => x.RegionId); //Primary Key
    }
}
```

How to address this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically changing schema in Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39499470/dynamically-changing-schema-in-entity-framework-core)

Comment: you can use Data Annotations approach by using Data Annotations 
[Table("blogs", Schema = "blogging")]

or 

you can use Fluent API
 modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
        .ToTable("blogs", schema: "blogging");

modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("blogging");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ToTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalentitytypebuilderextensions.totable?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_RelationalEntityTypeBuilderExtensions_ToTable_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_Builders_EntityTypeBuilder_System_String_System_String_) method:

```
public class RegionConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Region>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Region> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.RegionId); //Primary Key
        builder.ToTable("TableName", "dbo");
        // or  builder.ToTable(nameof(<entity>), "dbo");
    }
}
```

Comment: For EntityFrameworkCore 5, the .ToTable() method is no longer available. How would one accomplish the same thing with EFCore5?

Comment: @Solo812 The method ToTable [still available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.relationalentitytypebuilderextensions.totable?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_RelationalEntityTypeBuilderExtensions_ToTable_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_Metadata_Builders_EntityTypeBuilder_System_String_System_String_). Ensure, that you have added 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational package to project references.

Answer (score 2):

As an option, you can also use DataAnnotations instead as alternative to FluentAPI. Both are fine.

```
[Table("Region",Schema = "dbo")]
public class Region {}
```