# Set search_path dynamically for schema-based multi tenancy in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, multi-tenant, npgsql

I'm writing a new ASP.NET Core application (.NET Core 3.1) using EF Core for database access. This application should interface with an existing PostgreSQL database that has a PostgreSQL schema for each tenant. From what I read so far, this is not the way one would usually do this in .NET Core, but as the database already exists I don't have any choice here. I couldn't find any good information on how to dynamically switch schemas, the documentation for multi-tenant database access generally assumes different models than tenant-per-schema or different databases.

The table layout is identical in all schemas, so the only thing that has to happen is that the search_path is set to the correct schema for each request. I'm not sure how to do this exactly with EF Core, the documentation I found only addresses setting the schema statically or per model.

What is the correct way to handle this kind of multi-tenant setup in ASP.NET Core using EF Core?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would implement some sort of DbContextProvider that would take in the name of the tenant and return a DbContext. The implementation of this DbContextProvider would look something like the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39499470/dynamically-changing-schema-in-entity-framework-core).