# .Net Core Entity Framework Code First Approach Modify Schema Dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an application with  **.net core 3.1 web API** with **Entity Framework Code First Approach**  , which will handle different database schema  based on the request,

Consider there is a API, which trying retrieve customer details,

if the first request is `api/GetAllCustomer?schema="schema1"` then the system should retrieve the data from **schema1.customer** and if the request is  `api/GetAllCustomer?schema="schema2"` then the data should retrieve from **schema2.customer**

and if a new customer is created we need to create a new table called **schema3**

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Since it's Code first approach currently using MS SQL , future this might change with MySQL or PostGreSQL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically changing schema in Entity Framework Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39499470/dynamically-changing-schema-in-entity-framework-core)

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft , Not exactly , this  approach shows a predefined list of schema, but in my case schema is creating on runtime

Comment: The schema is just a string in the referenced answers.  This question is still a dupe.